# add data row wise if a condition is met in excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a data set with heading `['Q 36 Marks','Q 37 Marks', ..., 'Q 50 Marks']` in a data frame from an excel file. The data contained as 0.0, -1.0 or 4.0. And the data is of students appearing for an exam.
I want to create a new variable - score which will add the first 10 question marks for each student which are either 4.0 or -1.0. I am not able to do it using pandas.

like if the data is

```
Q 36 Marks Q 37 Marks ... Q 50 Marks (in all 15 questions) and for student the data is 
4          4      -1  0 0 -1 -1 4 -1 4 0 0 -1 -1 4
```

so the score should calculated as `4+4+(-1)+(-1)+(-1)+4+(-1)+4+(-1)+(-1)` the last 4 is not to be considered.

I tried finding the pandas functions `.sum(axis=1)` but not aware how to find the conditions to get only the first 10 non-zero entries into the sum function.

Comment: Performance is important? Added test to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the masked values to remove the unwanted data, then [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on only the first 10 values:

```
cols = ['Q 36 Marks','Q 37 Marks', 'Q 50 Marks']
df['Score'] = (df[cols] # only required if you want to filter some columns
   .where(df.ne(0)).stack()
   .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda g: g.head(10).sum())
)
```

Output (Score column only):

```
0    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for test only `-1, 4` values in filtered columns, get first `10` by test by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), set not matched values to `0` in [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and last sum per rows:

```
cols = ['Q 36 Marks', 'Q 37 Marks', ..., 'Q 50 Marks']

df['Score'] = df[cols].where(df[cols].isin([-1,4]).cumsum(axis=1).le(10), 0).sum(axis=1)
```

If need processing all columns:

```
#here chain mask is not necessary, because sum of 0 is 0
df['Score'] = df.where(df.isin([-1,4]).cumsum(axis=1).le(10), 0).sum(axis=1)
```

If need change condition, e.g. sum only `-1` values solution is changed:

```
m = df.eq(-1)
df['Score'] = df.where(m.cumsum(axis=1).le(10) & m, 0).sum(axis=1)
```

**Test of performance**, here 1500 rows:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([-1,0,4], size=(1500, 15)))
df.columns=[f'Q {x+36} Marks' for x in df.columns]


In [153]: %timeit df['Score'] = df.where(df.isin([-1,4]).cumsum(axis=1).le(10), 0).sum(axis=1)
4.76 ms ± 699 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#mozway solution
In [154]: %timeit df['Score'] = df.where(df.ne(0)).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(lambda g: g.head(10).sum())
319 ms ± 5.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```